# Story Identification - Short Story, Parody of Bremen Town Musicians with Record Producer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, anthology-book

This is a story I read that is a parody of the fable/fantasy story The Bremen Town Musicians. In the original story, a donkey, dog, cat, and rooster all end up agreeing to travel to Bremen Town together to become musicians, but - after outsmarting some thieves in a cabin - decide to stay there instead of continuing.

In this parody, which I believe was called "The Musicians of Bremen Town", the setup was more or less the same, but instead the dog gets shot and is dying, and the thieves are record producers. One of them records the dog's dying howls and turns it into a platinum seller. I do not remember the other details of what happened to the other animals, but I do remember it was *very* funny.

I read it in an anthology of short stories, I assume for children (as it was on the bookshelf of my elementary school teacher's library) but I am not sure. The other stories in the collection I do not remember, but they were generally less morbid. I do not have a clear publication date other than "at or before 2012", as I must have read the story before then.

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: @Spencer:  The donkey, the dog, the cat, and the rooster all talk and sing (or otherwise make music.)  It's a fairy tale.

Comment: @JRE https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy

Comment: There is a 2018 anthology called [Fairy Riot](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?872406) that includes a short story by John Olsen called _The Bremen Town Musicians_. Could that be it?

Comment: @JohnRennie To quote a review: "This story is about four older people that meet up and connect over old music."

In other words, I'm afraid not. It seemed unlikely given that this collection postdates my reading by almost a decade, but it seemed possible to have been an earlier story repackaged in a new collection.

Comment: @Spencer By that meta thread, this question is indeed off-topic. Which, if any, SE do you suggest I ask instead? I'd prefer to keep the question open if possible.

Comment: Probably [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't contain any SF or Fantasy elements, and OP agrees.

Comment: The musicians always had unusual musical talent for their animal nature in-story.